# PHP Autoloading With class_exists confusion

Tags: php

I am working on an application where i have quite a lot of PHP Classes and i write classes like below

```
<?php

if(!class_exists('AClass1')){
  class AClass1{
  }
}

?>
```

and likewise i have around 400 classes and also i use a php autoloader script 
https://github.com/varunsridharan/php-autoloader
Along with a classmap generator 
https://github.com/varunsridharan/php-classmap-generator

So what happens is that when i write a condition like below

```
if(class_exists('AClass1')){
  // Some Code To RUN
}
```

In the above code if the class `AClass1` not exists then it autoloads via `class_exists` function which is good for me

But when i write a  code like this in a file called ***aclass1.php***

```
<?php

if(!class_exists('AClass1')){
  class AClass1{
  }
}

?>
```

and if that file is loaded via above if condition then after loading the file it still loops into autoloader instead it just should register the class

so whats the good way to avoid looping into autoloader even if the file inside class source

1. Never use `class_exists` when registering a class
2. use `class_exists('CLASSNAME',false)` to avoid looping inside autoloader

Comment: Why don't you simply add a unique namespace to your files instead of putting in a bunch of `class_exists()`? Then you can have how many classes you want with the same name as long as they have different namespaces.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i have created my project with a namespace. but the only issue is that its a wordpress framework https://github.com/wponion/wponion

Comment: Why would you be checking if class, that you are about to define, exists? I mean sure you can use class_exists with false as 2nd argument. But it makes no sense to me, unless you are creating a "polyfill" of some kind. But if you are trying to prevent errors from multiple inclusion of the file, then just dont include the file multiple times. Easy as that...

Comment: Why does it matter if it is a wordpress framework? It's still PHP. And if you have them in namespaces, what's the point of the `class_exists()` in the first place? What issue are you actually trying to solve by using them?

Comment: @slepic sorry i am confused, :-(  do you mind explaining a bit

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i want to load class file based on the request so i use autoloader. but the issue here is that this framework can be pre packed with a lot of plugins / themes and to avoid conflict issues i used a custom version loader inside my framework to load the very latest version so i use `class_exists` check

Comment: But that's one of the reasons for using namespaces, you can have many classes with the same name but as long as they have different namespaces, there won't be any conflicts.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so you are saying that using `class_exists` is not needed if namespace is used right ?

Comment: Which part is confusing you? You simply cannot afford to have conflicting names with symbols defined by third parties. You should use a namespace to avoid conflicts like that. If you ask if AClass1 exists, what does it actualy mean? It means that the class is already defined, but is it your version or a third party version? You dont know, and since they can be a completly different thing, you can get totaly unexpected behaviour (fatal error probably).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple test to see if a include loop might exists:

#### test.php

```php
<?php

// The simpliest autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
  include __DIR__ . '/Hello.php';
});

if (class_exists('Hello')) {
  $hello = new Hello();
  exit('class exists');
} else {
  exit('class does not exists');
}
```

#### Hello.php

```php
<?php

if (!class_exists('Hello')) {
  class Hello {
  }
}
```

I put both these files in the same folder. Then I run:

```
php test.php
```

There is no error or loop. It simply prints:

```
class exists
```

But frankly, you do not need the `class_exists` check in your class file at all if you're using an autoloader. The autoloader would only be called if the class is not already exists in the current environment. So unless you would manually `include` a class file **after** it is autoloaded, you'll be fine.

If for some strange reason you might have that, use `include_once` instead of `include`.